# C vs MATLAB (make a matrix whose elements are random numbers uniformly distributed)

Tags: c, matlab, performance, random

I'm running the simulator with MATLAB.
However, it takes a few days.
Hence, I decided to change the code into C.
(First, I tried to use c-mex in MATLAB, but I think coding and debugging are very hard. mxType!!!?!?!? Thus, I decided to make C code using the visual studio 2017.)

In my MATLAB code, I used

```
x = [unifrnd(varmin(1),varmax(1),varnum,1),...
     unifrnd(varmin(2),varmax(2),varnum,1),...
     unifrnd(varmin(3),varmax(3),varnum,1)];
```

That is, x is the matrix of size varnum*3, whose 1st column is random numbers uniformly distributed from varmin(1) to varmax(1), 2nd column is random numbers uniformly distributed from varmin(2) to varmax(2), and 3rd column is random numbers uniformly distributed from varmin(3) to varmax(3).

When I make a matrix in C code, I will code like the follows:

```
srand(time(NULL));
for(j=1; j<3; j++) {
    for(i=1; i<varnum; i++) {
        x[i][j] = rand() % (varmax[j]-varmin[j]) + varmin[j];
    }
}
```

I am changing my code from MATLAB to C because the running time is so long. However, I think MATLAB handles a matrix at once, but C handles a matrix of size MxN by running M*N iteration.
Nonetheless, is the code below (C) faster than the code above (MATLAB)?
Also, is there any better codes to make a matrix having random numbers?

Comment: I recommend to use optimized c++ libraries such as [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250720/random-complex-matrix-in-armadillo-and-in-eigen) post shows that generating a random complex matrix in `eigen` is twice faster than the other c++ libraray `Armadillo`.

Comment: I recommend to to store data in `Disc`.

Comment: mex is quite easy, just convert everything to C types and back. you need 4 mex functions at max

Comment: @rahnema1 Unfortunately, I do not know the C++ at all. I really hope to learn C++ but I can't do now, sorry.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Okay, I am going to try to use C-mex!

Comment: Off topic perhaps but notice that indexing in C starts from zero so your for-loops should probably start from zero instead of 1

Comment: @4386427 Ah! Thank you. I made a mistake. That must be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Both MATLAB and C will run the random generation `M*N` times and you can't really get around that. In C it might be a bit more explicit, but in the end it's just an issue of typing rather than actual speed.

I would say that MATLAB is extremely fast if you use it the right way. That means leaning a lot on the built-in matrix operations and vectorizing the others as much as possible. The fact that it automatically parallelizes the computation for you is just topping on the cake.
If on the other hand you're doing a lot of manual for loops over large matrices you're likely to have problems. Mind you, newer versions of MATLAB know how to JIT that sort of code as well, but it's just not going to be as fast as a hyper-tuned builtin method.

So I'd avoid going outside MATLAB to C. At most do just some small functions in C where MATLAB really doesn't help you, but leave the rest in MATLAB.

Unless *you really know what you're doing*, you're unlikely to see a performance increase. In fact, I'll wager that you'll see a decrease in performance. And a guaranteed increase in development cost.

If resources permit I'd investigate getting a bigger machine for the team, or renting some compute resources from AWS/GCP. Though the logistics of getting MATLAB to work there might be prohibitive.

Comment: My code has so much for loops. My simulation has 10,000 time slots. In each time slot, it takes around 500 by 50 (2,500) iterations to converge the value. Plus, each iteration contains my heuristic routing function (iterate of the number of my nodes times edges). Here, I am simulating the code In the MonteCarlo fashion with 1000 times. Even if I change in C, is there no speed up? :(

Comment: This entire answer is opinion based. It's a fact that *fully optimised* C code will likely be faster than *fully optimised* MATLAB code, since there is an extra layer of interpretation when using MATLAB.  You have included a lot of speculation about what the use-case might be. Development set-up costs will in fact be reduced if you don't have to buy a MATLAB license in the first place, so again that is subjective. Recommending hardware despite not knowing anything about the OP's setup is, again, way out of scope. The question is poorly framed, and so your answer is off topic.

Comment: There _might_ be in this case. Seems like MATLAB is a poor fit. Are you using any special MATLAB functions or was it more the case that it was a language you knew and could get started quickly? There's a lot of places where you can go wrong in C - if you have a row-ordered matrix and access it in a column-order way, you'll get terrible memory access performance. Doing misaligned reads/writes as well will trigger that. Without more insights into what's going on we can only speculate. And as @Wolfie says, that's not a good idea. And not the format SO is good for.